# Very slow git clone in windows 10

Tags: windows, git, windows-10

```
git clone http://git.blender.org/blender.git
```

Trying to do this I got only 10KB/s. speedtest.net reports I have 12Mb/s download speed. I can play multiple YouTube videos in good quality with no problem. Download from any other website can reach between 8Mb/s to 10Mb/s. It only fails when using git clone. Why's it so slow?

I found an article which suggests updating OpenSSH. I did all the steps to update etc still got slow speed.

My system:

- Windows 10
- Latest Cygwin
- git 2.17
- OpenSSH_7.7p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2o  27 Mar 2018
- Internet speed 12Mb/s download

Comment: Do you have slow speeds cloning from a *different* git host (Bitbucket, Github, etc.)? It could be that server does not have a high speed connection or that it is throttling user speeds.

Comment: Great, thanks for the help. I think something wrong with the server.

Answer (score -1):

I'm always boring caused by it's very slow to git clone github repository.
I have searched some ways by myself, then also use those ways to try to resolve that problem. summarily, the methods mainly are seperated to following 2 :

1. To modify your computer's or server's dns, then flush the dns cache
2. After the domain of github repository address, add the 'cnpmjs.org'.

As a contrast result, the method 2 is obviously faster than method 1.
So, just make a try !!!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).